# 3 balls drawn from 1 urn - probability of getting exactly one color

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> An urn contains $5$ red, $6$ blue and $8$ green balls. $3$ balls are randomly
> selected from the urn, find the probability of getting exactly one red
> ball if the balls are drawn with replacement.

Source: doubt came from the similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294850/3-balls-drawn-from-1-urn-probability-all-same-color-with-without-replacement).

In the same line, my answer follows

> Total number of ways $=19^3=6859$
>
> Favorable ways $= 5×14×14+14×5×14+14×14×5=2940$
>
> Probability $=\dfrac{2940}{6859}$

Is my understanding right? please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: I have not done the multiplication. But the structure of your answer is correct. The probability is $\frac{(3)(5)(14^2)}{19^3}$.

Comment: this is correct

Comment: use Binomial distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer works. Another way to solve this is to note that because draws are done *with replacement*, the draws are independent and identically distributed. Thus the random variable $X=\text{number of red balls chosen in 3 draws}$ is a [binomial random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $n=3$ and $p=\text{probability of red ball on a given draw}=\frac{5}{5+6+8}=\frac{5}{19}$. Thus

$$P(X=1)=\binom{3}{1}\cdot \left(\frac{5}{19}\right)^1\cdot \left(1-\frac{5}{19}\right)^2= \frac{2940}{6859}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Total number of ways $=19^3=6859$

Favorable ways $= 5×14×14+14×5×14+14×14×5=2940$

Probability $=\dfrac{2940}{6859}$

Comment: Sine my approach and answer was correct, adding it as an answer here.